# How to selecct subform current record value when the subform souce object is a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

When the subform source object is a form, it is easy just use Me!OrderNumber to select the current record of order number,  but when the subform souce object is a query, then I can not use Me!OrderNumber. I want to know how I can still select the order number when source object is a query or table.

Comment: Welcome to stachoverflow. please read how to ask question in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
OrderNumber = Me!NameOfYourQuery.Form!OrderNumber.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, Gusta. My mistake is to use the .Order instead of the !OrderNumber. In this situation, the . is not working. I do not really understand why this must be a .  because if the subform souce object is a form, the . or the ! both working.

Comment: It works nicely here, so can't tell. `NameOfYourQuery`is the name of the subform control. `Form` is a property of this.